# How to get rid of power failure problems while using Linux?

Tags: linux

I am using Linux. My daily working directory is present on a VFAT partition of my disk. Always I mount it and do my work. When power failure happens this directory sometimes gets corrupted and 'file saving' or 'file removal' results in an error "read-only file system'. After 2-3 unmount/mount the problem goes away. But, mostly I loose some *saved* and unsaved changes that I have done to my files. How to get rid of such power failure problems?

Very much surprised that my bios setting also getting changed sometimes, including date time! Don't know how to get rid of this as well.

Comment: See `man sync`.  If power failures are common for you, you might want to do that as a cron job every few minutes.

Comment: Do. Not. Use. VFAT. as your main working directory. Actually, don't use it at all, if you want cross compatibility with windows, use NTFS (but again, not as your $HOME).

Comment: @goldilocks How would `sync` work after a power failure? Wouldn't the file system buffers in memory be wiped out?

Comment: @JosephR : o_O I did not mean to use it *after* the failure.  I meant it could be used to minimize problems *in case of* a failure, if you happen to be plagued by them.

Comment: Date/time issue in the BIOS is probably due to a failing on board battery.

Comment: You get a [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several problems here.

1. As stated in comments, don't use VFAT as your primary working directory. Most of the linux filesystems are much better.
2. Have you considered investing in a UPS? Even a small one that can give the computer time for a normal shutdown would benefit you greatly.
3. The BIOS thing is a separate problem. I'd suspect the mother board battery and/or a problem with the power supply causing issues. A UPS would help solve this too.
4. sync is a tool that forces everything from caches out to the disk. If you really can't do anything else, then setup a process that calls 'sync' every so often. This will minimize the data in memory, and therefore minimize the number of problems you have when you reboot.
5. After you've got problems, you'll want to run fsck on the disk to clean up the problems. Read the man pages and run it BEFORE you re-mount the disk for best results.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is picking a better filesystem. You're using a non-journalling filesystem which might be fast but really isn't doing you any favours. This is what you need to change right now. Use EXT4 or something like that.

The next step is fixing your power. Power outages can be mitigated pretty well these days if can throw enough money at the problem. a UPS (uninteruptible power supply) will condition the quality slightly and will carry the PC for minutes in an outage, giving you time to save your work.

If the power quality is the problem (spikes and brownouts), dedicated conditioners and battery back-ups and generators will all help but they're not cheap to buy or install. If this is part of a company, it may be a justifiable offset against downtime.

If the power issues are hardware related, that's clearly something you should be looking to fix. Abrupt outages aren't good for hardware.

Your BIOS issues are probably related to a dead CMOS battery. These are usually CR2032 button batteries located on the motherboard. They're cheap and usually last a few years.